# catboost eval_metrics return value

Tags: decision-tree, catboost

I'm using `CatBoostClassifier`'s `eval_metrics` to compute some metrics on my test set, and I'm confused about its output. For a given metric, by default, it seems to return an array, of size equaling the number of iterations.

This seems to be inconsistent with the `predict` function, which returns a single value only. Which number in the array returned by `eval_metrics` is consistent with the `predict` function?

I checked the documentation at https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/python-reference_catboostclassifier_eval-metrics.html#python-reference_catboostclassifier_eval-metrics__output-format, but it's still not clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

The Catboost classifier is a type of Ensemble Classifiers which uses Boosting Methods. Simply put, Boosting algorithms iteratively train weaker algorithms (Decision Trees in this case) to make predictions. Each Tree that is created learns from the collective errors that the previous weaker trees made and tries to learn from those errors. Catboost is based on Gradient Boosting which I won't dwell to deep into. What is relevant here is that a number of weaker trees are generated in the process, and when you call the `eval_metrics()` method you are getting the eval metric for each of the generated trees. You specify the number of trees generated when you provided `iterations`, `num_boost_round`, `n_estimators` or `num_trees` when creating the model (If not specified it has a default value of 1000).

The other arguments you specify to the `eval_metrics()` method will define the range of trees taken `ntree_start` to `ntree_end` at intervals of `eval_period`. If these aren't provided you will get the specified metrics for your data for all of the weaker trees generated, which is why you get a list of values.

Comment: Hi Ranika, thanks for your explanation here. The `predict` function only outputs 1 value (by default it sets `ntree_start` and `ntree_end` to both 0), not a list. So this 1 value is the ensemble of all the trees?

Comment: As you may have noticed the `predict` function doesn't have an `eval_period` so instead of considering intervals it considers the trees from `ntree_start` to `ntree_end`  which are both set to 0 by default meaning it takes all the trees generated to make a prediction. If you set `ntree_start=0` to `ntree_end=iterations` or whatever value used, you should get the same output.

Comment: Ranika, so if we consider the other side of the coin - what if we want to get the same default behavior of `predict`, now with `eval_metrics` (using all the trees), which number of the array output by `eval_metrics` should we use? The last or the first perhaps?

Comment: Not really sure if that is possible, will have to look into that